# Accessing dynamically created checkbox in user control from container page

Tags: asp.net

I am building a wizard in asp.net. I have an main aspx page which will have NEXT and PREVIOUS button for Navigation. On click of each NEXT or PREVIOUS appropriate user control will be loaded.

In one user control I have to create dynamic checkboxes as shown below:

```
    Public Class ucQuestion
    Inherits System.Web.UI.UserControl


#Region "UserControl Events"

    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        Try
            If Not (Page.IsPostBack) Then
                AddControls(0)
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            Throw ex
        End Try
    End Sub

#End Region
Protected Friend Sub AddControls(ByVal iListQuestionCount As Integer)
        Try
            Dim oExam As New BusinessObject.Wizard.ExamVM
            If (System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session(BusinessLayer.Constants.WizardObjectCollection) IsNot Nothing) Then
                oExam = DirectCast(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session(BusinessLayer.Constants.WizardObjectCollection), BusinessObject.ExamWizard.ExamVM)
            End If

            'divQuestion.Controls.Clear()

            Dim ctrl As New Literal

            ctrl.ID = "lit" + iListQuestionCount.ToString()
            ctrl.Text = oExam.Wizard.ExamQuestions(iListQuestionCount).Label
            divQuestion.Controls.Add(ctrl)

            For iLoopChildCount As Integer = 0 To oExam.Wizard.ExamQuestions(iListQuestionCount).Choices.Count - 1
                Dim childctrl As New CheckBox
                'childctrl.AutoPostBack = True
                childctrl.ID = "chk" + (iLoopChildCount + 1).ToString()
                childctrl.Text = oExam.Wizard.ExamQuestions(iListQuestionCount).Choices(iLoopChildCount).Label
                childctrl.Checked = oExam.Wizard.ExamQuestions(iListQuestionCount).Choices(iLoopChildCount).IsSelected
                'AddHandler childctrl.CheckedChanged, AddressOf OnCheckedClick
                divQuestion.Controls.Add(childctrl)
            Next

        Catch ex As Exception
            Throw ex
        End Try
    End Sub
```

NoW the problem is in my Main.aspx page if user has selected any checkbox in usercontrol I want to save the value in session on NEXT button Navigation click event.

I tried following code in NEXT Button Click but it was unsucessfull.

```
For iLoopChildCount As Integer = 0 To oExamQuestions(ListIndex).Choices.Count - 1
                Dim ctrl As Control
                If (ucQuestion1.FindControl("chk" + (iLoopChildCount + 1).ToString()) IsNot Nothing) Then
                    ctrl = DirectCast(ucQuestion1.FindControl("chk" + (iLoopChildCount + 1).ToString()), CheckBox)
                    If (DirectCast(ctrl, CheckBox).Checked) Then
                        oBallotQuestions(ListIndex).Choices(iLoopChildCount).IsSelected = True
                    End If
                End If
            Next
```

Answer (score 0):

That's the hard way.

Here is the easy way.

1. Define an [interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/28e2e18x%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) and implement it in the User Control that represents this action. This might be `GetNamesOfSelectedValues` or whatever is appropriate. (Technically an interface isn't required, but I find it good practice and it makes for "more well defined contracts" in many cases.)
2. Use the interface defined on said Child in the Parent page code. Use this only *after* the `OnLoad` of the Child Control (which happens *after* the page load event) or the controls will not be restored yet.

That is, the parent *should not know about* any controls in the custom User Control.

This approach works well.

Comment: I couldn't understand could you please give an example

Comment: Well, first start by defining an interface (see link): what does the parent *NEED* to know/access? Then make the class `implements` that interface.